# Facebook login with PHP v4 sdk

Tags: php, facebook

I just set up facebook login with PHP sdk with my app.

I approved the app and got sent back to my site. But now nothing happens, session will always be null and can therefore not gather information from facebook.

I used the basic example with some few modifications

```
// Load autoloader for facebook
require_once(Application::getAppRoot()."/libs/facebook/autoload.php");

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

Facebook\FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(FB_APPID, FB_SECRET);

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper(FB_REDIRECT_URI);
echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl(['email']) . '">Login with     Facebook</a>';
try {
        $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
        // When Facebook returns an error
} catch(\Exception $ex) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo $ex->getMessage();
}
if ($session) {
        // Logged in
        var_dump($session);
}
```

Shouldn't this be enough to get data from facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake in this situation was that i outputed a login url before checkin for a valid session.

So for others in a simular situation, only output / run the method for loginUrl after you have checked for a valid session